# Can't run binary executable on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I get the following error: `./cataclysm: command not found` when trying to run this executable on a Linux server over SSH.

when I run `ldd cataclysm`, I get:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7759000)
liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0 (0xf7716000)
libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0xf76e6000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf76c6000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75d2000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf75a6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7588000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf73de000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf73d8000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf775a000)
```

Is everything ok here?

Also it's a 64-bit server so I also installed `ia32-libs`, as a I thought this might be the issue, but it's still not working

Edit: solved now, just needed `chmod 755 cataclysm`

Comment: Try "file ./cataclysm" to see what type of file it is.  It might be the wrong architecture, and file should show you what it is.

Comment: Try to check if your libraries are available at the path shown by ld. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/248512/why-do-i-get-command-not-found-when-the-binary-file-exists

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a 32-bit binary (you can tell by the **/lib/i386-linux-gnu** in the ldd output). I think you have the issue figured out after installing 32bit libs and fixing file permissions, but for others who may have the same problem, see [this Ubuntu guide on running i386 code on amd64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit).